# App Access in Google Play for App Approval - Issue: Invalid or incomplete login credentials

Tags: flutter, google-play

I have been struggling to publish my app on google play. My app has phone authentication step for signing in. I have created a test number which when provided as a phone number, an anonymous account is created enabling all the functionalities of the app.

Yet still my app is rejected.
[Rejection mail from google play] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNnkb.png)
[Sign in page in my app] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/txA26.png)

I don't know how to overcome this step. Please help, this is my first app to publish.

These are the instructions I added for the app access in google play console:

*Steps to reach the app main pages:

1- The welcome page contains 2 buttons: تسجيل الدخول (sign in) and حساب جديد (new account)

2- click on the red button: تسجيل الدخول (sign in) button. It will navigate you to the sign in page.

3- In the phone number place holder, under the title رقم تليفونك (your phone number), add the given test number: 01096653796

4- Do not change the country code number (keep it: +20)

5- press on the red button saying تسجيل الدخول (sign in)

6- you are navigated into the app *

I referred to all the links provided for by the support, but I don't know how to overcome this problem as the test number works fine on all my emulators and real devices, so there is nothing wrong with the signing in process.
These are the links I searched in:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455#app_access
https://playacademy.exceedlms.com/uploads/resource_courses/targets/1056751/original/index.html?_courseId=480215#/page/63067b117157aac8def8d1ec

Was my approach of creating an anonymous account a bad idea for letting google play testers access my app? what can I do instead?

Comment: Have you provided the proper credential details in App content -> App Access? If yes, does your app have access in specific countries?

Comment: Yes I did provide correct credentials. My app is only available in Egypt.